# Weight python array so a[0] is x times the size of a[-1]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Hi all looking to weight an array so that the first value , a[0] , is x times the size of the last value, a[-1] . Additionally, i'd like this to be linearly decayed, ie equal parts between each value in the array.

```
mult = 3
a = [1, 1, 1, 1]

# These conditions should hold true:
# a[0] * 3 = a[-1]
# (a[1] - a[0]) == (a[2] - a[1])
```

Comment: If the old values of `a[0:-2]` aren't needed, you aren't really weighting the array; you're just defining a new one with the same length in terms of `a[-1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html):

```
out = np.linspace(mult*a[-1], a[-1], len(a))
# or
# out = np.linspace(mult, 1, len(a))
```

Output:

```
array([3.        , 2.33333333, 1.66666667, 1.        ])
```